# Does sunscreen/suncream stop the amount of skin tan?

Tags: safety

I know that SPF blocks a given amount of UVA/UVB rays, so does the lack of UV rays reaching my skin mean that I won't get a tan, and if so, what's the best way to get a tan safely?

For example, would using a lower SPF in a very sunny place like the Caribbean be dangerous?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to travel

Comment: @Newton It is tangentially related to travel.  The strength of the sun is actually regional due to the amount of particulates in the air (as well as altitude).  And people who have no experience of how strong the sun can get in some places can get into a lot of trouble with exposure.  I'd also say that the OP's question is akin to "Should I drink the local water".

Comment: The safest way to get a tan is probably [sunless tanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunless_tanning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind, Tanning is merely the least bad form of sun exposure.  Meaning, there is no 'safe tan'.

Generally yes, a lower SPF will allow a more controlled burn leading to a tan.  *However, you need to know your limits beforehand.*  Tan 5-10 min MAX per day to see how you react, the rest of the time, stick with the 50.

Also, you can **burn in one exposure**, but a tan may take 2-3 days to materialize.

Comment: Best statement I saw a while back is that "A tan is a radiation burn"

Comment: Seriously, no comment on the Downvote?  How unhelpful and totally wrong.  Should totally ignore.